# What is equivalent of $not in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

With a schema like

```
var ApplicationActivitySchema = new Schema({
  datetime: {type: Date},
  activity: {type: String},
}, {_id: false});

var ApplicationSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  status: {type: String, required: true, enum:['Pending','Yes','No']},
  activities: {type: [ApplicationActivitySchema], key: 'datetime'}
});
```

In mongodb shell I can run a query like

```
db.applications.find({'status':'Pending','activities.datetime':{$not:{$gt:new Date()}}})
```

to list pending applications with no future activities.  I have tried for quite a while to do the same thing in Mongoose but not found the answer - can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share what did you tried on mongoose ? , because you can use mongo's operators in mongoose methods generally.

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by Ilker I tried again with putting it into a find() and it worked fine - I must have mistyped it when I tried before.

What an idiot.